# What is the difference between these Telephony SMS/MMS classes?

Tags: android, sms, telephony

I would like to read all SMS and MMS messages into a ListView using Android's Telephony content provider. When I look at the classes, I see many results, including these:

- [Telephony.Mms.Inbox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Mms.Inbox.html) - Contains all MMS messages in the MMS app inbox.
- [Telephony.Sms.Inbox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Inbox.html) - Contains all text-based SMS messages in the SMS app inbox.

---

- [Telephony.MmsSms](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.MmsSms.html) - Contains all MMS and SMS messages.

---

I cannot find any more information about these classes. I notice, however, that the first two inherit from [BaseMmsColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.BaseMmsColumns.html) and [TextBasedSmsColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html), respectively, in which we have constants like `BODY`, `ADDRESS`, etc. we can read. MmsSms does not have this; it inherits only from [BaseColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html) which give us the ID and number of rows.

So my question is, what exactly is Telephony.MmsSms? I would expect from the description that it was simply a merging of both MMS and SMS messages but I don't understand how I'm meant to access the content of those messages, if at all. What is the recommended way to combine both MMS and SMS messages using Telephony?

Comment: SMS is short messaging service, MMS is multi-media messaging service. A big distinction is the size of the message, and if I am not mistaken this plays a role into why SMS messages are limited in text size by some providers.

Comment: I'm aware of the distinction; I was wondering specifically about the method of retrieving them. What does Telephony.MmsSms actually do? Or should I ignore that and try combining the two Inbox tables?

Comment: Querying the [`MmsSmsProvider`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/telephony/MmsSmsProvider.java) - using the `MmsSms` `Uri`s in that class - effectively does that, for any/all the boxes. The linked code and its comments might clear some things up for ya.